# Learn Russian very very fast

Tags: self-learning, russian

I know the Russian alphabet, and I know how to present myself in Russian (say my name, say my age...). I have two weeks to have a correct "Russian level" and I can work 1 hour a day.

By saying a "correct Russian level" I mean :

- Understand the essential points when a clear and standard language is used and if things are familiar in work, school, leisure...
- You get by in most situations encountered while traveling in an area where Russian is spoken.
- Produce simple and coherent speeches on familiar topics and areas of interest.
- Tell an event, experience or dream, describe a hope or purpose and briefly explain reasons or explanations for a project or idea.

Yet, to learn that fast Russian I need an extremely precise timetable, like: each day I learn 30 new Russian words... Yet, to optimize the learning I don't know what my timetable should be ? Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are expected to have such skills in two weeks, but you are living in a dream world. It is not going to happen.

Comment: According to Common European Framework of Reference for Languages, which is what you seem to have used, you want to get to level B1 (aka Threshold or intermediate) in 14 hours. According to the same framework, it could take a learner 350-400 hours to get to the same level in English. Please keep everyone updated on your efforts!

Comment: Learning words is not the most important part of learning a language: any decent Taboo player can get away with knowing just the basic vocabulary and being good at pantomime. Languages differ not with what you can say, but what you must say (i. e. grammar), and mastering grammar is what distinguishes a person naming things and making gestures from a language speaker. Mastering grammar (especially Russian grammar) requires seeing or hearing it used and using it in speech or writing. You can't possibly read or hear enough grammar to get a grasp of it within the timeframe you have defined.

Comment: You can begin  with Pimsleur Learn To Speak Russian.  It's level 1 is 15 hours long, which is close to your time allotment.  It's a structured approach from absolute zero to something.  It will teach you vocabulary and basic grammar for a few standard situations (directions, money, food, drink etc.).  Like everyone else said it's only the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you can dedicate 100% of the time of the next 14 days (14 × 24 = 336 hours) to learning Russian, your goal is effectively impossible.

As mentioned in the comments, your goal is to attain [B1 fluency (A2 if we're being lenient with our definitions)](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/444/85) in 14 hours of study.

A2 fluency is attained at ~200 hours of study. B1 takes more than 300 hours.

Two weeks is an unreasonable timeframe to expect to achieve that level of fluency. Fourteen hours even more so.

---

If it's really urgent, get offline and start studying. You won't make your goal, but good luck anyways.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do all of that in two weeks. You could get proficient progress in some parts, but not all.

Like mentioned lots of times here, not only must you practice and learn new words, you must use them in some ways. Learning only one hour a day for a total of 14 hours will only let you remember *a few words*. That is not enough for you to remember and use properly 420 words in Russian and meet with the rest of your requirements.

With only 14 hours of study, you're not only even close to getting *basic communication* according to the CEFRL according to this [answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/440/how-does-the-cefrl-work/444#444):

> A1 users are beginners; very basic communication is the extent of their abilities, and they may need help from the person they're speaking to. Usually achieved around 100 hours of study.

You can though focus only on one thing and try it as good as you can at that. Otherwise, there is no way for you to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

For level A2 approximately you need to know 1000 words.
You have 1 hour daily for 2 weeks. That is you have to learn 1000/14=71 words per day. Try it and you will get an answer to your question.

Comment: You may need to provide some references to back these numbers.